# How can I use a camera matrix with different resolutions?

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I created a little jump'n'run game. The character(Mario) is always the center of the viewport. The game is running correctly if I use the resolution 800x480 pixel. But when I use another resolution(for example 1280x768), the sprites in the viewport look completely different to the sprites in the 800x480 viewport. I want that the viewport(and the sprites in the viewport) looks always the same, on every single resolution.

How can I do that? Should I change something on my camera matrix parameters or what should I change so that the viewport and the proportions of the sprites look always the same?

I use Monogame to run the game on different Windows Phone devices.

My camera class:

```
 public class Camera 
{ 
    public Vector2 Cameraposition; 

    public Camera(Vector2 cameraposition) 
    { 
        Cameraposition = cameraposition; 
    } 

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 CamPosition) 
    { 
        Cameraposition = CamPosition; 
    } 

    public Matrix GetMatrix() 
    { 
        return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, Cameraposition.X, Cameraposition.Y, 1, 0, -Cameraposition.X, -Cameraposition.Y, 0, 1); 
    } 
}
```

In Game1:

```
//I use the camera in Game1 like this:
//At the beginning(in LoadContent): 
Vector2 cameraposition = new Vector2(PlayerStartpos.X - GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, PlayerStartpos.Y - GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2); 
camera = new Camera(cameraposition); 

//Updating the camera position
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        player.Update(gameTime); 
        Newcameraposition = new Vector2(player.Playerposition.X - GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, player.Playerposition.Y - GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2); 
        camera.Update(gameTime, Newcameraposition); 

        base.Update(gameTime); 
    } 

//Drawing: 
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullNone, null, camera.GetMatrix()); 
 ...
```

Comment: Your camera class has to take into account the aspect (width / height) of the screen.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of creating the matrix manually, try using the helper functions such as `Matrix.CreateTranslation(positionX, positionY, 0));`

Comment: @Fletcher D  That doesn't help me because the GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width and GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height are not considered. Is it possible to change the camera matrix so that it fits for every single resolution?

Comment: @Homer_Simpson I don't think Fletcher means to use that code *specifically*. You can [multiply matrices together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Composing_and_inverting_transformations) to combine their operations. For example: you could combine a translation matrix (as per Fletcher's example) and a scaling matrix (`CreateScale`) that considers the viewport size. Order is important. This will make your code far clearer and easier to work with, than creating a matrix element-by-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not an *exact* duplicate, so I won't try to close it. But it's close enough that I feel comfortable in simply sending you over to my old answer on [**Supporting Multiple Resolutions**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31684/288).

That answer is specifically for the [XNA Platformer Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/platformer), so you should probably download a copy of that to play around with to get a feel for how the code in my answer works. Then you can apply it to your own game.

---

Note, in particular, how I use matrix multiplication to combine two matrix operations, as mentioned in comments on your question:

```
Matrix camera = Matrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, 1)
        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translateX, translateY, 0);
```

Comment: Is "Matrix.CreateTranslation(positionX, positionY, 0));" the same as "new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, Cameraposition.X, Cameraposition.Y, 1, 0, -Cameraposition.X, -Cameraposition.Y, 0, 1);"? Because I get a different result if I move my camera with "Matrix.CreateTranslation(positionX, positionY, 0));".

Comment: No, they are not the same. However your custom matrix does not appear to be performing any kind of *sensible* transformation operation. Which is another good reason to construct your transformations from the `Create*` methods. A translation matrix is: `(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, X, Y, Z, 1)`.

Comment: I added the scaling, but now the input isn't working correctly.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson That's a separate problem - please create a separate question for it (add links between the two, if you like). I've reverted your question to its original state. Please don't keep tacking additional questions onto a question that's already been answered.