# How I support different display resolutions?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a 2D windows phone game. The game should look the same on every windows phone device. But I have no idea what to do so that my game looks great on every display resolution. How can I do that? What is the best/easiest way?

I don't like letterboxing. So I tried scaling the sprites but that looks blurry(very bad). 
My sprites are all in PNG format. I created them in Inkscape.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/how-would-you-handle-different-aspect-ratios-in-a-2d-platformer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way seems to be scaling the sprites.  You can create alternate images to handle differing resolutions and load them depending on the screen's resolution.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447674%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx)